# Where on Ko Samui can I find a clean, non-tourist beach?

Tags: thailand, beaches

I am going to Thailand in a few months but I still don't know where to stay. I read many things about the northern islands. Some of them are beautiful but very touristy. Is there any place that is nice, but still without many tourists?
I am thinking somewhere next to Ko Samui.

Comment: "Yes." - doesn't make for a useful Q/A though does it.

Comment: Find a quiet place in Krabi

Answer (score 11):

I lived on Ko Samui about 7 months from september 2013 to march 2014. I visited all the beaches of the island several times each one of them.

Most touristic

1. Chaweng and Lamai
   As far as I can remember the most most touristic beaches are Chaweng and Lamai, but even so this doesn't mean that this beaches was full of tourists.

Golden mean

2. Mae Nam
   I lived near Mae Nam from october 2013 to january 2014. I think this is the golden mean: not so many tourists and clean beaches.

Least touristic

3. Lipa Noi
   I was on Lipa Noi beach several times and every time I saw there a few people.
4. Taling Ngam
   My friends lived near Taling Ngam beach and they told that this is the most quiet place on Ko Samui.
5. Bang Po
   I lived near Mae Nam from january 2013 to march 2014. Also quiet place, but mane seaweed in the water near beach.

[image]

Comment: What makes you say those places?

Comment: Cause I was there and saw those places ;)

Comment: @choster ok I'll complement my answer with some details

Comment: @vitalkr - Thanks, that's a great answer now. We know what seasons you saw the state of these, and that you aren't just basing your opinion off one visit to each place.